# maximizar o restaurar un formulario en c#

Tags: c#

estoy intentando usar botones para maximizar o restaurar un formulario en c#
ya intente este codigo pero no me funciona

```
private void Maximizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            Restaurar.Visible = true;
            Maximizar.Visible = true;
        }
        private void Restaurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            Maximizar.Visible = false;
            Restaurar.Visible = true;
        }
```

pero no me funciona, ya busque documentación pero no me ayudan... por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

No acabo de ver el problema, solo que el código correcto sería

```
private void Maximizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        Restaurar.Visible = true;
        Maximizar.Visible = true;
    }
private void Restaurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Maximizar.Visible = false;
        Restaurar.Visible = true;
    }
```

Lo que he cambiado en tu código es

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

del procedimiento `Restaurar_Click`, aunque lo puedes mejorar con

```
private void Maximizar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized) {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            Maximizar.Text = "Restaurar";
    } else {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Maximizar.Text = "Maximizar";
    }
}
```

Y te ahorras un botón.